# Image preview in Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a Cordova mobile app and I'd like to let the user open a jpeg in preview mode to zoom, pan or share the picture

problem no.1
- the jpeg is a base64 string inside my app. It is not a file on the filesystem

problem no.2
- I couldn't find any suitable plugin. Opening the image on the default image viewer would be good

I addressed the first problem by saving the base64 data to a temp file on the filesystem so actually only the second part of the problem is the real blocker

I tried implementing a custom plugin with the following code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(url)), "image/jpeg");
    ctx.startActivity(intent);
    callbackContext.success();
```

but I get the following error:

> Error well opening file: exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()

Comment: just reinstall the Cordova custom plugin! it should work! this error seems to be having an old version of plugin! had it solved back then by just a reinstall! !

Comment: Done it multiple times to no avail